Is this argument roughly analogous to the fine tuning argument?
So, it is said that certain constants within the physical laws are “fine tuned” for life in the sense that if they were any different, life would not exist. The probabilistic form of the argument is highlighted by the SEP here:

Proponents of the argument from fine-tuning for design argue that, in view of the required fine-tuning, life-friendly conditions are highly improbable if there is no divine designer; see Barnes 2020 for a careful case for this claim. Thus, the conditional probability
P
(
R
∣
¬
D
)
should be set close to zero. In contrast, it is highly likely according to them that the constants are right for life if there is indeed a designer. Thus the conditional probability
P
(
R
∣
D
)
should be given a value not far from
1
. If a sufficiently powerful divine being exists—the idea goes—it is only to be expected that she/he will be interested in creating, or at least enabling, intelligent life, which means that we can expect the constants to be right for life on that assumption. This motivates the likelihood inequality …..


which expresses that life-friendly conditions confirm the designer hypothesis and which likelihoodists such as Sober (2003) regard as at the core of the argument from fine-tuning for design.

In the passage above, R is the observation that the constants seem fine tuned for life and D is our credence in the design hypothesis. Since R is supposedly more likely under the design hypothesis than not, this should at the very least give us more credence in the design hypothesis.
Now, let’s imagine another argument. Suppose that I draw 52 cards from a deck. This results in a particular sequence of cards which we will now call X. Let’s define R as the observation that we got this particular sequence X of cards. Let D be the credence in a designer hypothesis where there exists a designer that wanted that particular sequence to come about.
Clearly, P (R|D) is 1. P (R|~D) is extremely low. Does this give us a reason to now prefer this designer hypothesis, and is it roughly analogous to the fine tuning argument?

@KristianBerry Fair enough although I’m not sure how that’s relevant to the meat of the inference in the fine tuning argument. The analogy was moreso trying to highlight that no matter how “improbable” an event is, one can construct a hypothesis in such a way as to make that event probable. But since this can be done with any improbable event, what is it about the fine tuning designer hypothesis that makes it more likely than any of the infinite presumably ad hoc hypotheses that can explain any improbable event?

@KristianBerry Rearrangements and sample spaces depend on your mind though, not reality. One can for example imagine the process of someone drawing a card from a deck and have it magically turn into a new kind of card, or turn into a butterfly, or whatever else. This creates many more outcomes. This seems physically impossible but physically impossible just means “these events don’t accord to our model of reality.” But then where is the evidence that universes given other constants are real and not just imagined?

@KristianBerry why does there need to be an explanation in the first place? There’s nothing incoherent about just assuming that there’s only one set of constants and one universe. P.S. all constants occurring doesn’t explain why only a minisicule range in that infinite number of constants is life inducing

No, it is not analogous.  To be analogous, life would only be possible if there are 4 straight suits in the shuffled deck, and thee are 4 straight suits after shuffling.  If you think that doesn't call out for an explanation, you are not a scientist.

@Syed I added 'cosmology' in replacement of 'universe' which I forgot to replace with a better one in my last edit. By the way, I've noticed a systematic laziness regarding tag assignment in your questions. Questions about God without tags related to God, questions about epistemology without the epistemology tag, questions about probability without the probability tag, questions that should have multiple tags with only one tag, etc., etc.

I can't resist mentioning the extremely strong anthropic principle, which says that the universe was created so that somebody would eventually mention the extremely strong anthropic principle.

@ScottRowe: I'm not sure whether that weakens it to the Very Strong Anthropic Principle, or enhances it to the Even More Extremely. But, yeah; it's a humorous illustration of the problem of assuming that what happened at the time it happened was the only way it could have happened. I'll show myself out. Remember to tip your admins.

In the actual context of the real Universe being designed/not being designed, “fine-tuning” is not real:

Let X be any combination of fundamental constants and initial conditions, and let L(X) be the set of species that evolve in the Universe with initial conditions and fundamental constants X.
Let the “neighborhood” N(X) of X be the set of all Y such that L(X)≈L(Y); that is, the neighborhood of X is the space of all combinations that are, in terms of life produced, equivalent to X.
Let the “diameter” D(X) of a combination X be a measure of the maximum deviation of fundamental constants and initial conditions of the most disparate combinations in N(X): the diameter of a combination X tells you by how much you need to change X to evolve significantly-different life, i.e. to leave the neighborhood N(X). The diameter of most neighborhoods is known to be small by numerical analysis; conditions for the rest of the Universe vary wildly based on initial conditions and constants.
Since any life that ever evolves would not have been able to evolve if conditions were much different (i.e. if the conditions were outside their neighborhood) all by definition, then life L*, if it evolves, sees the Universe as being fine-tuned because the Universe had the combination X that was precisely in N(X), precisely because if X were not in N(X) then L* could not have evolved (we establish that L* evolves, and then note that this implies that X lies in a neighborhood where L* evolves as a requirement of this).
Therefore, any life L* observes the Universe to be fine-tuned.

Note that this doesn’t have to be human life, and that X does not end up mattering in the final point. Then, given that all life everywhere always no matter what the initial conditions were observes fine-tuning, the fact that we observe fine-tuning does not imply anything - simply that we were capable of making the observation that the Universe appears fine-tuned.
Preferring a designer hypothesis is, well... It’s a fallacy to say that just because something wildly improbable happened meant that someone had their metaphysical finger on the scales, it just meant that something improbable happened. Consider also the case where it is actually 100% probable for any life to evolve to see fine-tuning, from the previous logic, and all of a sudden, the issues relating to fine-tuning and designer hypotheses disappear.

This is an incorrect response, and reveals that you have not read any Fine Tuning papers.    The point of Fine Tuning is that the vast majority of the operating space of the Standard Model will not support any life at all.  If all matter condenses into black holes, there will be no matter for interactions.  If the universe recollapses in 15 seconds, there will not be the deep time needed for abiogenesis or evolution.  If the expansion rate stays very high, then no matter will coalesce, and no complex chemistry can develop.  Your PRSUMPTION of life -- is the point at issue!

Actually, that doesn't change anything. My logic still holds: any life that does evolve will still see it as fine-tuned, and obviously life did evolve in our Universe. Why did that happen? That's the same as asking why I just rolled five 20s in a row on a d20. The occurrence of improbable events does not imply unfairness. If multiple Universes happened to contain life, then that might be evidence that a designer was putting a finger on the scales - but of course, we have only one data point, and thus cannot draw any conclusions on the fairness of the Universal die.

Consider also: all other logic failing, the fact that we cannot explain why the constants and conditions are and were what they are and were does not imply that there is a designer making it so, it just means that we don't know everything yet. Lightning, tsunamis, earthquakes, the seasons, night and day, birth and death all used to be explained away by designer-like gods as well, but just because they were not understood at the time does not imply that they do not have a perfectly-rational and designerless explanation. Same goes for fundamental constants and initial conditions.

Quine-Duhem thesis -- that there are likely an infinity of possible models we have not yet discovered that could match our data -- is true for all scientific and empirical inference.  It is not justification to throw away the inferences that we have found that fit our data, just because someday we may find another.  Are you rejecting all inference, or making a specials pleading case for rejecting design inferences?

It is not the case that in a generic universe the conditions for life would appear to be radically improbable.  That is a false claim, and is contradicted by your own invalid assumption in your answer.  That in OUR universe, its compatibility with eventual life seems to have been radically unlikely, is a significant observation, and the sort of thing actual scientists go looking for a possible explanation for.

There do exist an infinite number of scientific models that could fit our current data arbitrarily well, but the specific model of a conscious being orchestrating everything is one we have exceptionally little/no direct evidence for, and anyway the Quine-Duhem thesis is an instance of Russel's teapot. It could be that there exists an entity that just produces the appearance of QM and GR and everything in the minds of scientists - a perfectly valid model of the world - but it's not on anyone else to disprove that entity's existence.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
